# How can I setup a supportedRuntime 3.5 as minimum?

Tags: .net, frameworks, version, app-config

It there a setting for supportedRuntime in the app.config to run only on version 3.5? For example with the SKU?

Currently we have the problem that our application crash with a method not found error if it run with .NET framework 2.0. This give a bad feedback to the customer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "sku" attribute isn't supported until .NET 4.0

And it is not the real problem.  You don't have a dependency on 3.5, you have one on .NET 2.0 SP1 or SP2.  And the client is running the RTM version of 2.0.  Microsoft made a mistake in the service pack updates, it sneaked in a few method overloads that were not available in the RTM version.  Without changing the [AssemblyVersion] of the assemblies, it is still 2.0.0.0

That was very, very naughty and has caused plenty of pain.  Addressed in .NET 4, the reference assemblies are now no longer a plain copy of the assemblies in the GAC.

Basic ways to address this problem:

- include the .NET 3.5SP1 bootstrapper in your installer.  Which will ensure your client's PC is updated with the latest service pack
- just fix your code and avoid the dependency on the added method overload.  You ought to know the name from the exception.  Taking a guess, the odds are good that it is WaitHandle.WaitOne(int).  Added in SP2 and widely favored over the equivalent WaitOne(int, bool) with the last argument set to *false* since nobody understands what *exitContext* might mean
- the not-so-helpful but realistic approach: point out to the client that you cannot support machines that don't have Windows Update turned on.

Answer (score 2):

[`<supportedRuntime>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4atty68.aspx) is only present to determine the CLR version - which is the same for framework versions 3.5 and 2.0. I don't *know* of any way of requiring .NET 3.5 in terms of startup parameters.

Having said that, it should be relatively straightforward to create an entry point which first probes for .NET 3.5 assemblies, and gives a friendly error message if they're not found. Of course that will depend on what kind of application you're running, but if it's a local GUI (WPF or WinForms for example) then it shouldn't be too hard.